# Logging in Scala

Tags: logging, scala

What is a good way to do logging in a Scala application? Something that is consistent with the language philosophy, does not clutter the code, and is low-maintenance and unobtrusive. Here's a basic requirement list:

- simple
- does not clutter the code. Scala is great for its brevity. I don't want half of my code to be logging statements
- log format can be changed to fit the rest of my enterprise logs and monitoring software
- supports levels of logging (ie debug, trace, error)
- can log to disk as well as other destinations (i.e. socket, console, etc.)
- minimum configuration, if any
- works in containers (ie, web server)
- (optional, but nice to have) comes either as part of the language or as a maven artifact, so I don't have to hack my builds to use it

I know I can use the existing Java logging solutions, but they fail on at least two of the above, namely clutter and configuration.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

## slf4j wrappers

Most of Scala's logging libraries have been some wrappers around a Java logging framework (slf4j, log4j etc), but as of March 2015, the surviving log libraries are all slf4j. These log libraries provide some sort of `log` object to which you can call `info(...)`, `debug(...)`, etc. I'm not a big fan of slf4j, but it now seems to be the predominant logging framework. Here's the description of [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/):

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

The ability to change underlying log library at deployment time brings in unique characteristic to the entire slf4j family of loggers, which you need to be aware of:

1. *classpath as configuration* approach. The way slf4j knows which underlying logging library you are using is by loading a class by some name. I've had issues in which slf4j not recognizing my logger when classloader was customized.
2. Because the *simple facade* tries to be the common denominator, it's limited only to actual log calls. In other words, the configuration cannot be done via the code.

In a large project, it could actually be convenient to be able to control the logging behavior of transitive dependencies if everyone used slf4j.

#### Scala Logging

[Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) is written by Heiko Seeberger as a successor to his [slf4s](https://github.com/w11k/slf4s). It uses macro to expand calls into if expression to avoid potentially expensive log call.

> Scala Logging is a convenient and performant logging library wrapping logging libraries like SLF4J and potentially others.

## Historical loggers

- [Logula](https://github.com/codahale/logula), a Log4J wrapper written by Coda Hale. Used to like this one, but now it's abandoned.
- [configgy](https://github.com/robey/configgy), a java.util.logging wrapper that used to be popular in the earlier days of Scala. Now abandoned.

Comment: Gotta say, I love Logula...finally a logger that doesn't make me want to stab screwdriver up my ear. No xml and no BS, just a scala config on startup

Comment: Heiko Seeberger's SLF4S no longer appears to be maintained. I made my own targeting Scala 2.10 and the latest SLF4J. [http://slf4s.org/](http://slf4s.org/)

Comment: Logula is abandoned according to its README on Github.

Comment: Oncue Journal is similar in concept to Scala Logging, but the log messages are sent to an actor which calls SLF4J from a dedicated thread pool. Trades CPU time for (much better) latency. https://github.com/oncue/journal

Answer (score 65):

With Scala 2.10+ Consider ScalaLogging by Typesafe.  Uses macros to deliver a very clean API

https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging

Quoting from their wiki:

> Fortunately Scala macros can be used to make our lives easier: ScalaLogging offers the class `Logger` with lightweight logging methods that will be expanded to the above idiom. So all we have to write is:

```
logger.debug(s"Some ${expensiveExpression} message!")
```

After the macro has been applied, the code will have been transformed into the above described idiom.

In addition ScalaLogging offers the trait `Logging` which conveniently provides a `Logger` instance initialized with the name of the class mixed into:

```scala
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging

class MyClass extends LazyLogging {
  logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
}
```

Comment: Use `class MyClass with Logging`.

Comment: Please note that using logging in traits causes the trait to have the same name for the logger as the class it is mixed into. I think you can get the logger manually instead of the macro convenience to provide the logger name manually, if needed. But please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does this mean MyClass has public methods for debug, info warn etc? If so I'd rather do the extra manual work of instantiating a logger private to the class. Logging methods should not leak into a classes interface.

Comment: you get a logger field, which you can use at your leisure. See https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging/blob/master/scalalogging-slf4j/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/slf4j/Logging.scala for details

Comment: 2.x requires Scala 2.11; hopefully there's not much practical difference; for Scala 2.10.x, there's `"com.typesafe" %% "scalalogging-slf4j" % "1.1.0"`.

Comment: Seems the class is in `com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging`.

Answer (score 14):

Using slf4j and a wrapper is nice but the use of it's built in interpolation breaks down when you have more than two values to interpolate, since then you need to create an Array of values to interpolate.

A more Scala like solution is to use a thunk or cluster to delay the concatenation of the error message.  A good example of this is Lift's logger

[Log.scala](http://github.com/dpp/liftweb/blob/fe26cc3bff335b4f428194cf4c2e7f6818fb0cbe/lift-util/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/util/Log.scala)
[Slf4jLog.scala](http://github.com/dpp/liftweb/blob/fe26cc3bff335b4f428194cf4c2e7f6818fb0cbe/lift-util/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/util/Slf4jLog.scala)

Which looks like this:

```
class Log4JLogger(val logger: Logger) extends LiftLogger {
  override def trace(msg: => AnyRef) = if (isTraceEnabled) logger.trace(msg)
}
```

Note that msg is a call-by-name and won't be evaluated unless isTraceEnabled is true so there's no cost in generating a nice message string.  This works around the slf4j's interpolation mechanism which requires parsing the error message.  With this model, you can interpolate any number of values into the error message.

If you have a separate trait that mixes this Log4JLogger into your class, then you can do

```
trace("The foobar from " + a + " doesn't match the foobar from " +
      b + " and you should reset the baz from " + c")
```

instead of

```
info("The foobar from {0} doesn't match the foobar from {1} and you should reset the baz from {c},
     Array(a, b, c))
```

Comment: is it possible to get accurate line numbers for logging statements in scala classes?????

Answer (score 13):

### Don't use Logula

I've actually followed the recommendation of Eugene and tried it and found out that it has a clumsy configuration and is subjected to bugs, which don't get fixed (such as [this one](https://github.com/codahale/logula/pull/4)). It doesn't look to be well maintained and it **doesn't support Scala 2.10**.

## Use slf4s + slf4j-simple

### Key benefits:

- **Supports latest Scala 2.10** *(to date it's M7)*
- Configuration is versatile but couldn't be simpler. It's done with [system properties](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html), which you can set either by appending something like `-Dorg.slf4j.simplelogger.defaultlog=trace` to execution command or hardcode in your script: `System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simplelogger.defaultlog", "trace")`. No need to manage trashy config files!
- Fits nicely with IDEs. For instance to set the logging level to "trace" in a specific run configuration in IDEA just go to `Run/Debug Configurations` and add `-Dorg.slf4j.simplelogger.defaultlog=trace` to `VM options`.
- Easy setup: just drop in the dependencies from the bottom of this answer

Here's what you need to be running it with Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.weiglewilczek.slf4s</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4s_2.9.1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where do you find slf4s that supports 2.10?  I'm looking at https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s and see "Supported Scala versions are 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.9.0-1 and 2.9.1." .. am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Brian Use the 2.9.1 as suggested in the answer. I've tested it to be working fine with 2.10.0-M7

Comment: I'm using 2.9.1, I was just curious about the highlighted "key benefit" and what that means.

Comment: After carefully searching through the answers for the pros and cons of the logging libraries, I choose the one that tells me what dependency to import. Thanks, Sir.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I got [Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) working for me:

Put this in your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2",
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

Then, after doing an `sbt update`, this prints out a friendly log message:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging._
object MyApp extends App with LazyLogging {
  logger.info("Hello there")
}
```

If you are using Play, you can of course simply `import play.api.Logger` for writing log messages: `Logger.debug("Hi")`.

See the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging) for more info.

Comment: Only worked for me after I created `log4j.properties` inside project resource folder.

Answer (score 11):

### Logging in 2020

I was really surprised that [Scribe](https://github.com/outr/scribe) logging framework that I use at work isn't even mentioned here. What is more, it doesn't even appear on the first page in Google after searching "scala logging". But this page appears when googling it! So let me leave that here.

Main advantages of Scribe:

- it is **NOT** a slf4j wrapper
- supports also Scala.js and Scala Native
- it is *really* fast, check comparison here: https://www.matthicks.com/2018/02/scribe-2-fastest-jvm-logger-in-world.html

Comment: This looks really nice! It's unclear if it's possible to change the logging level via configuration though?

Comment: You can use `scribe.Logger.root.clearHandlers().clearModifiers().withHandler(minimumLevel = Some(Level.Error)).replace()` as mentioned in https://github.com/outr/scribe/wiki/getting-started for setting it globaly. If you want to use configuration file you have to use a library like [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) or just use program arguments in your custom configuration class. I just put global config setting line mentioned before in my custom trait that extends App trait and it works fine.

Comment: You an also configure it per class but I have never needed it because I work with microservices.

Comment: I don't mean in code, I mean using a file. E.g. If I want to debug something, I am not going to recompile my code to turn debugging on

Comment: You will have to implement something on your own. Scribe just gives us tools to implement our own mechanisms for configuration, not the mechanisms themselves.

Comment: Ah! OK, that sounds fine.

Comment: Typical of scala. Just the minimalist library that works efficiently. No opinions about configuration. Thats the nice thing I liked about scribe

Answer (score 8):

I use SLF4J + Logback classic and apply it like this:

```
trait Logging {
  lazy val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  implicit def logging2Logger(anything: Logging): Logger = anything.logger
}
```

Then you can use it whichever fits your style better:

```
class X with Logging {
    logger.debug("foo")
    debug("bar")
}
```

but this approach of course uses a logger instance per class instance.

Answer (score 7):

I pulled a bit of work form the `Logging` trait of `scalax`, and created a trait that also integrated a `MessageFormat-based` library.

Then stuff kind of looks like this:

```
class Foo extends Loggable {
    info( "Dude, I'm an {0} with {1,number,#}", "Log message", 1234 )
}
```

We like the approach so far.

Implementation:

```
trait Loggable {

    val logger:Logger = Logging.getLogger(this)

    def checkFormat(msg:String, refs:Seq[Any]):String =
        if (refs.size > 0) msgfmtSeq(msg, refs) else msg 

    def trace(msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger trace checkFormat(msg, refs)

    def trace(t:Throwable, msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger trace (checkFormat(msg, refs), t)

    def info(msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger info checkFormat(msg, refs)

    def info(t:Throwable, msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger info (checkFormat(msg, refs), t)

    def warn(msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger warn checkFormat(msg, refs)

    def warn(t:Throwable, msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger warn (checkFormat(msg, refs), t)

    def critical(msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger error checkFormat(msg, refs)

    def critical(t:Throwable, msg:String, refs:Any*) = logger error (checkFormat(msg, refs), t)

}

/**
 * Note: implementation taken from scalax.logging API
 */
object Logging {  

    def loggerNameForClass(className: String) = {  
        if (className endsWith "$") className.substring(0, className.length - 1)  
        else className  
    }  

    def getLogger(logging: AnyRef) = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerNameForClass(logging.getClass.getName))  
}
```

Comment: Cute, though I'm having some issues getting this to work -- specifically, the output (on default slf4j configuration) always looks something like the following, instead of the class actually extending Loggable:
Jul 22, 2011 3:02:17 AM redacted.util.Loggable$class info
INFO: Some message...

Any chance you've ran into this?

Answer (score 5):

`Writer`, `Monoid` and a `Monad` implementation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Combination of those could create a nice "log" attach to your result. IMO, it is a little bit overkill. But if you want to learn something new http://blog.tmorris.net/the-writer-monad-using-scala-example/

Comment: @Tg. The link in your comment is dead. Use http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/the-writer-monad-using-scala-example/

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at the scalax library :
http://scalax.scalaforge.org/
In this library, there is a Logging trait, using sl4j as backend.
By using this trait, you can log quite easily (just use the logger field 
in the class inheriting the trait).

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried it yet, but Configgy looks promising for both configuration and logging:

http://github.com/robey/configgy/tree/master

Answer (score 3):

Quick and easy forms.

Scala 2.10 and older:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("TheLoggerName"))
logger.debug("Useful message....")
```

And build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" %% "scalalogging-slf4j" % "1.1.0"
```

Scala 2.11+ and newer:

```
import import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("TheLoggerName"))
logger.debug("Useful message....")
```

And build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"
```

Comment: Where do you get the logs afterwards?

Comment: Usually there will be a configuration file, such as log4j.properties, that specifies where the logs are output. See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

Comment: Cool. Will check it.

Answer (score 2):

After using slf4s and logula for a while, I wrote `loglady`, a simple logging trait wrapping slf4j.

It offers an API similar to that of Python's logging library, which makes the common cases (basic string, simple formatting) trivial and avoids formatting boilerplate.

http://github.com/dln/loglady/

Answer (score 2):

I find very convenient using some kind of java logger, sl4j for example, with simple scala wrapper, which brings me such syntax

```
val #! = new Logger(..) // somewhere deep in dsl.logging.

object User with dsl.logging {

  #! ! "info message"
  #! dbg "debug message"
  #! trace "var a=true"

}
```

In my opinion very usefull mixin of java proven logging frameworks and scala's fancy syntax.

Comment: @sschaef, oh, yes. Sorry. I've almost forget. It was a great fight with this issue for a few days, but looks like this is really impossible. I've used #! ! "info message" instead. I'll edit edit my answer.