# Scala : trying to get log4j working

Tags: scala, logging

Scala newb here (it's my 2nd day of using it).  I want to get log4j logging working in my Scala script.  The script and the results are below, any ideas as to what's going wrong?

```
[sean@ibmp2 pybackup]$ cat backup.scala
import org.apache.log4j._

val log = LogFactory.getLog()

log.info("started backup")
[sean@ibmp2 pybackup]$ scala -cp log4j-1.2.16.jar:. backup.scala
/home/sean/projects/personal/pybackup/backup.scala:1: error: value apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.log4j._
           ^
one error found
```

Comment: The punctuation at the end the jar file name could be the problem.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/978252/203968

Answer (score 2):

I reproduce it under Windows: delimiter of '-classpath' must be ';' there (not ':'). Are you use cygwin or some sort of unix emulator?

But Scala script works anywhere without current dir in classpath. Try to use:

$ scala -cp log4j-1.2.16.jar backup.scala

JFI: LogFactory is a class of slf4j library (not log4j).

**UPDATE**

Another possible case: broken jar in classpath, maybe during download or something else. Scala interpreter does report only about unavailable member of the package.

```
$ echo "qwerty" > example.jar
$ scala -cp example.jar backup.scala
backup.scala:1: error: value apache is not a member of package org
...
```

Need to inspect content of the jar-file:

```
$ jar -tf log4j-1.2.16.jar
...
org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
...
```

Comment: The problem is happening on Centos Linux

Comment: @Fred Scala from system rpm package or custom installation at the HOME dir?

Comment: I downloaded the latest scala version and installed it under /usr/local

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to put log4j.jar in your classpath?

Comment: I have the log4j jar file in the same directory as my .scala source, and I tried running scala with -cp log4j-x.x.jar as an argument, didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Had Similar issue when started doing Scala Development using Eclipse, doing a clean build solved the problem.

Guess the Scala tools are not matured et.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using log4j directly, you might try using [Configgy](https://github.com/robey/configgy).  It's the Scala Way™ to work with log4j, as well as configuration files.  It also plays nicely with SBT and Maven.

Answer (score -1):

[I asked and answered this question myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215664/configure-logback-for-sbt-scala-project), have a look:

> Put it under `src/main/resources/logback.xml`. It will be copied to the right location when SBT is doing the artifact assembly.