# What project directory should logback.xml be in SBT/Scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt, logback

I have an SBT/Scala project and logback seems to work, but totally ignores my `logback.xml` config file.  I have placed at `src/main/scala/logback.xml`. It doesn't do anything.

What is the correct location for it?

Can anybody post an example of an SBT/Scala skeleton project with a working `logback.xml` file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put it under `src/main/resources/logback.xml`. It will be copied to the right location when SBT is doing the artifact assembly.