# logback can't seem to find logback.xml under SBT?

Tags: sbt, logback

Having transferred a working project into SBT, I've noticed that logback can't seem to find `logback.xml` - even when it's in `src/main/resources/logback.xml`. Or anywhere else for that matters, e.g. `classpath`. Has anybody else had this problem?

Here is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "goGame"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.0" % "1.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.0.13"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13" 

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scct" % "scct_2.10" % "0.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.3"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"
```

Comment: `src/main/resources` is the place I'd use for such files. What does logback print out that makes you feel it can't find the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [configure logback for sbt / scala project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215664/configure-logback-for-sbt-scala-project)

Comment: Hi Jacek, thanks for your reply. The logging is definitely happening as I can see log4j style [info] messages. But when I try and modify the logback.xml it makes no difference what level I set individual classes to. Even if I delete the logback.xml file I still get exactly the same logging messages. I think everything is being logged. Interestingly when I create the file on the src/main/resources and run sbt.. the file does get automatically copied into a classes area but I see no evidence it is being used :(

Comment: I don't know logback so can't help much, but my suggestion would be to  (mimic what SBT does and) use `logback.xml` on the command line to have it picked up?

Comment: Finally fixed by removing unnecessary dependencies and being more careful about blank lines (that weren't) in the build.sbt file.

Comment: Could you post the solution as an answer and approve?